# Tkinter Project downloadable

Tags: python, tkinter

I made this small project for practice with python and tkinter but I was just wondering is there a way to make it an installable application for people to use it? or am I suppose to use a different program for that? I did try looking it up and couldn't find anything on it. If anyone could help me out I would be so thankful!!

[image]

Comment: Take a look at Py2exe or my personal favorite Pyinstaller
http://www.pyinstaller.org/
http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: Yeah, PyInstaller is my fav too, but there's some problems if you wanna use it under win10, (1) because some dll librares do not actually exist in win10 (`api-ms-win-crt-*.dll`, more [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1566)), (2) upx-packer under win10 loves to break your DLLs (dont know why). Maybe there's more problems, but, as i said, PyInstaller is a best tool, if you ask me.

Comment: There is also [cx_freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this: py2exe, PyInstaller, CXFreeze...
Here is how to do it with py2exe.

1. Download and install the correct version of py2exe for your system using `pip install py2exe` in CMD as Administrator or download and install it manually from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/).
2. Create a python script in the same directory as your code; the convention is to call it `setup.py`.
3. In the script, paste the following code:

   ```
   from distutils.core import setup
   import py2exe
   setup(console = ["you_filename_here.py"],
   ```

   (remember to replace `your_filename_here.py` with your project's main python file)
4. Open another CMD window, change directory to where your project is (e.g. `cd C:\Projects\TestProject`), type the following, and press enter.

   ```
   python setup.py py2exe
   ```

This will create a lot of output - don't worry about that - and will create a directory called `dist` which contains all the files you need to run the program on any computer without needing to install Python. Since `tkinter` is a default python module, you should not need to do any additional work. However, if you use this in future with other modules, you may need to do some extra fiddling to get it to work (just google it!)

There are many ways to create `.msi` files (i.e. installers) such as [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).