# how do I make a Tkinter project downloadable? -

Tags: python, tkinter

how do I make a Tkinter project downloadable by other computers which don't have python installed, on macOS?

py2exe works only for windows and I couldn't find a way to do it on Mac.

[this question answers it for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082088/tkinter-project-downloadable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Py2App, a similar program to Py2Exe.
There are many tutorials on how to use it, so try it!

Comment: You also need to set `argv_emulation` to `False`, in order to make the main window show.